# Xamarin Android Linker - Removes Firebase messaging classes

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, xamarin-linker

I have a Xamarin Forms app with a corresponding Xamarin Android project. I use Azure Notification Hub for managing pushes to the app and FCM for the Android piece. The app has been functional for a while in the above setup.

Everything works great with the app when the Linker is set to `"None"` but the final download size of my app is huge. Setting the Linker property to `SDK Assemblies Only` does not cause any build errors but causes the push notifications to break. When a notification is pushed to the device the app crashes (foreground or background).

The error I log with Firebase Crashlytics is `java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver> cannot be instantiated`. I understand the Linker probably removed ***"unused"*** classes one of which is probably the required Firebase class.

I have tried adding various modifications of namespaces, class names, assembly names, etc to the `Skip Linking assemblies` option and none seem to help with the issue

[image]

I am also trying to `Enable MultiDex` on this app, but without the linker, it crashes the app on initial load. With the Linker Enabled, Multi-Dex seems to work fine as well.

Comment: The None setting is not usually recommended for production builds. The linker will sometimes remove code that you want to preserve. You could use the Android.Runtime.Preserve attribute to preserve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker